# How to add swipe right to android application from end of screen?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working in my android application then i had a problem, i want to add swipe right or left to my app to handle something when user swipe but i want user to swipe from end of screen not center like this example. [1]: https://imge.to/i/v3OaQT "Example"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code you need to add to your `Activity`.

```
var x1 = 0.0f
var x2 = 0.0f
val minSwipeDistance = 150f

val displayMetrics : DisplayMetrics? = null
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics( displayMetrics )
val margin = ( displayMetrics!!.widthPixels * 0.2f ).toInt()

bottom_app_bar.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    when( event.action ) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            x1 = event.x
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            x2 = event.x
            val delta = x2 - x1
            val absDelta = Math.abs( delta )
            if( absDelta > minSwipeDistance && delta > 0.0f && x1 < margin ) {
                // Handle the further actions
            }
        }
    }
    v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
}
```

From the `DisplayMetrics`, we obtain the screen's width in pixels. Then, we obtain the `margin` from where the action needs to be performed by reducing the width ( by multiplying it with 0.2 ). See the image below.

[image]

Hence, we check whether the `event` 's x1 is smaller than the margin. Also, we verify the swipe distance `delta` is greater than 0 indicating that it was a swipe right action. At last, we check that the swipe distance is greater than `minSwipeDistance`. If all the conditions are satisfied, we can perform further actions.

**Note**: You can adjust the `minSwipeDistance` and the `margin` ( the constant `0.2` being multiplied ) according to your needs.

Comment: thanks, i got how it works but can you give me an example in java cause my project written in Java and i cant compile it?